# ERROR: The ejabberd node 'ejabberd@localhost' is already running

Tags: ejabberd

1. I am installing ejabberd but when I run this through terminal using `./start` command. It gave the error that the ejabberd node `ejabberd@localhost` is already running.
2. I have uninstalled the ejabberd and again installed it through installer but
   it gave the same error.

Comment: What OS are you using ? How did you install it ? Package ? Binary installer ? Which version of ejabberd is it ? Do you find beam running when you type command `ps aux` ? In which directory ? Is it same place from where you installed ?

Comment: i am using OSX 10.10.3 and i am using this link to install ejabberd https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/

Comment: try to use ejabberdctl instead of start scripts. Moreover, check if you set up hosts section correctly

Answer (score 5):

I face similar issue, using ubuntu as operating system.

I simply use command ps -aux | grep -i 'ejabberd' which list down ejabberd processes. Than I kill all those processes (by collecting process ID's from above command than use command e.g "kill 98167 87654").

This fixed problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I tested from fresh install with OSX ejabberd installer on OSX 10.10.4 and after install I can start ejabberd just fine.

So, it seems that you already have something running in your environment that is interacting with ejabberd / ejabberd installer in a bad way.

Here is what you need to check:

1. Check if ejabberd is actually running with the following ejabberdctl command:

   $ bin/ejabberdctl status

   You can also try starting / stopping ejabberd directly with `ejabberdctl stop` and `ejabberdctl start`
2. Check the Erlang running processes with `ps aux | grep beam`. Here is what I get when ejabberd is actually running:

   $ ps aux | grep beam
   mremond         53977   0.0  0.2  2526548  41872   ??  S     7:47PM   0:01.73 /Applications/ejabberd-15.06/bin/beam.smp -K true -P 250000 -- -root /Applications/ejabberd-15.06 -progname /Applications/ejabberd-15.06/bin/erl -- -home /Users/mremond -- -sname ejabberd@localhost -noshell -noinput -noshell -noinput -pa /Applications/ejabberd-15.06/lib/ejabberd-15.06/ebin -mnesia dir "/Applications/ejabberd-15.06/database/ejabberd@localhost" -ejabberd log_rate_limit 100 log_rotate_size 10485760 log_rotate_count 1 log_rotate_date "" -s ejabberd -sasl sasl_error_logger {file,"/Applications/ejabberd-15.06/logs/erlang.log"} -smp auto start
3. Check what you see in `/Applications/ejabberd-15.06/logs` files. Pay specifically attention to `error.log` and `install.log`

Comment: I add ./ejabberdctl status in terminal. Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@localhost: nodedown

Commands to start an ejabberd node:
  start    Start an ejabberd node in server mode
  debug    Attach an interactive Erlang shell to a running ejabberd node
  iexdebug Attach an interactive Elixir shell to a running ejabberd node
  live     Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode
  iexlive  Start an ejabberd node in live (interactive) mode, within an Elixir shell

Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node:

Comment: It says that Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@localhost: nodedown

Comment: Appsters-MBP-Akshay-Kumar:logs akshay$ /Applications/ejabberd-15.06/logs/ejabberd.log
-bash: /Applications/ejabberd-15.06/logs/ejabberd.log: Permission denied

Comment: I have checked my install logs.  Script output  not coming. I have matched my install logs with another guy. In my case script output is missing and in his case its showing .Script output:

       -=- ejabberd post installation script -=- 
              (c) 2005-2015 ProcessOne 

* Checking ejabberd installation

* Starting ejabberd instance

* Creating administrator user
User admin@appsters-mbp-ravi-ranjan.local successfully registered

Comment: It seems you may have right issues. Can you try installing ejabberd in a subdir of your home directory instead to check if this is better ?

Comment: Thanks Mickel .Its working now. I have changed the location  for directory from application to AnotherFolder then it will easily installed .Thanks dude .